# Way to get windows version without using WMI class "Win32_OperatingSystem"

Tags: vbscript, wmi

I wish to get the windows version (say Operating System) without using the WMI class **Win32_OperatingSystem** using VBScript. Is there a way?

The reason I wish to do this is because I run the VB Script on NT machine which do not support WMI and I am not able to find installable for WMI for NT 4.0. Also it would be good if I am **not dependent** on WMI and would prefer getting the windows version without WMI using VBScript.

Please help !!

Thanks,

Nayan

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's impossible to move off NT4 and that RPC is enabled, you can [get it](https://superuser.com/a/267474) from the registry:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\\BuildLab
```

`%systemroot%\windows\system32\prodspec.ini` [has the information](http://forum.sysinternals.com/exact-windows-version-in-registry-key_topic1902.html) in the section `[Product Specification]`, followed by "`Product=`", with the name of the OS version following the equals sign. If you need the VBScript code to extract this information then add a comment stating as much and I'll add it in.

With RPC available, PSEXEC would also be an option.

Also, if you have active directory then the information is there, too, though it's possible for it to not be authoritative if your re-imaging process has "issues". If you need VBS code to pluck it from AD, post a comment with this request and I'll add it.

It goes without saying, though, that you should move off NT4. No patches in years. If it's impossible then consider virtualizing the system and putting it behind a well-configured firewall like ISA or Outpost Agnitum to block all protocols and ports to all hosts except as explicitly needed for essential functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the version from the `ver` command:

```
Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set ver = sh.Exec("%COMSPEC% /c ver")
Do While ver.Status = 0
  WScript.Sleep 100
Loop
version = ver.StdOut.ReadAll
```